# How can I prevent Windows 10 from uninstalling apps without my permission if it deems the app incompatible after an update to Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, compatibility

After the recent major update (from an existing Windows 10 installation, to a newer version of Windows 10), bringing me up to version 1511 build 10586, I received a message in the notification area informing me that one of my apps had been removed due to incompatibility with the new version of the OS. The notification linked me to [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-incompatible-app).

No files were available from the previous installation. Upon reinstallation, the program works fine, however I could very easily imagine this process could have resulted in a loss of data. In this particular case, it did not matter.

How can I prevent Windows from uninstalling apps without my permission, regardless of whether it deems the app incompatible?

Comment: Aren't they backed up in `Windows.old`? I know there's a way to do it, but I'm worried it may corrupt another function tied to it during the installation process.

Comment: You can't.  You normally would run the compatibility check before installing the update, this would prevent, the programs just being silently removed.  It would never result in data loss, since the application is simply never installed again, in the case like this Windows was basically installed again which of course means they are located in `Windows.old`

Comment: Ah, they do appear to be in windows.old, yes

Comment: @Ramhound Surely it should run that and notify you *before* you run the update?!

Comment: To clarify, this was from a Windows 10 build, to a new windows 10 build. I shall edit the question.

Comment: I have no idea how you applied to update.  My experience Windows was basically installed again but I installed by mounting the .ISO.  I have not updated a system to Version 1511 through Windows Update but I suspect the process is identical.

Comment: @enigma - You don't have to update your question.  Windows 10 was still basically installed again.....If it wasn't then `Windows.old`. would not have been created.

Comment: @Ramhound it was an update though Windows update, with very little user interaction required (I pressed the restart now button)

Comment: @enigma - When I performed the update.  I got the familiar installation screen, it went through 3 phases, before the update was installed.